# Does a limit of a function in a limit point equals only lateral limit on one side?

Tags: limits, continuity

I have a function that goes like this:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\log(x)^{\log(x)}&x >  1\\
      a&x = 1
\end{cases}$$
I need to find a so that this function is continuous for $x = 1$.
Therefore, i need to calculate the lateral limits of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $1$.
How do i calculate the limit as $x$ approaches $1$ from left if the function is not defined for those values?

Comment: You can only calculate the right hand limit and check if it is equal to $f(1)$. This is called one sided continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not defined for $x<1$, therefore we need to evaluate

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+} \log(x)^{\log(x)} =\lim_{x\to 1^+} e^{\log x \log(\log(x))}$$

form which we can find the value for $a$ which assures continuity.